# Sessions mix up in Express

Tags: node.js, express, session

I have created simple application with sessions using the express framework, but after I get sign in on one system and another user signs on another system, when I refresh my page it has changed to the account details of the user who has signed in last.

I don't know where I have made my mistake.

in Login.js

```
global.sess = null;

app.post("/signin", function(req, res) {
  sess = req.session;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;

  const userData = {
    email: email.trim(),
    password: password.trim()
  };

  if (!req.body.email) {
    req.flash('error', 'Enter a Valid Email address');
    return res.redirect('/signin');
  }
  if (!req.body.password) {
    req.flash('error', 'Password should not be Empty.')
    return res.redirect('/signin');
  }

  // find a user by email address
  User.findOne({
    email: userData.email
  }, (err, user) => {
    console.log("user...", user);
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error', 'User details is not found for this email, please register....');
      return res.redirect('/signin');
    }

    // check if a hashed user's password is equal to a value saved in the database
    user.comparePassword(userData.password, (passwordErr, isMatch) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      if (user.status == 'Suspended') {
        req.flash('error', 'Your Account is Suspended. please contact the admin');
        return res.redirect('/signin');
      }
      if (user.status != 'Active') {
        req.flash('error', 'Your Account is Not Verified. please Verify');
        return res.redirect('/signin');
      }
      if (!isMatch) {
        req.flash('error', 'Incorrect email or password, please try again..');
        return res.redirect('/signin');
      } else {
        sess.user = user;
        req.flash('success', 'Login successful');
        res.redirect("/eventica");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

In app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = module.exports = express();
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'ssshhhhh'
}));

app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
var flash = require('express-flash');
app.use(flash());

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

global.sess = null;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  sess = req.session;

  if (req.session.user) {
    res.render('eventica', {

    });
  } else {
    res.render('firsteventica', {

    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The fact that you explicitly create a global session is likely the only clue needed. There's just one, because it's global. Why?

Comment: when i commented the line global.sess=null; it does same

Comment: A session is *per user*. You can't have a global session object. That defies the purpose, because it would be the same object for all users.

Comment: Now i have taken the global.sess=null, still it does not work

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the user information globally `global.sess` which is not the right way to store the session. You can make use of passport.js for user authentication and maintaining a session.

Comment: I need to do using express-session

Comment: @DvThiyanesh This problem of having global session can be resolved by making use of a node module called `connect-redis`. If you wanna know how you code needs to be modified to make use of connect-redis, I can edit my above answer. Hope this helps :-)